# PhpStorm 7.0 compiled css autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, yeoman

I just created a little web app with **[yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)**. On liveedit mode, compiled css are stored in my .tmp folder and are not included directly on my html file, it uses special url.

File structure:

```
.tmp/
    main.css
app/
   index.html
   styles/
      main.scss
```

Inside my index.html:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This is default template of an yeoman webapp.

So for the auto-completion, how can i tell PhpStorm to look on the generated files inside the folder `.tmp`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this :( Only selectors from .css files explicitly included in .html via `<link>` tag are available for completion inside this .html. So you need to add a `<link>` tag to be used for completion and remove it in production